# Why do I get error messages when trying to save or exit from Rstudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

I deal with a problem in R Studio. When I choose to save my work, this message shows up
[image]

And if I try to close the program, this message shows up
[image]

Any ideas why this happens? Also, I would like to ask if it is better to use the latest version of R (R4.0.2)?

Comment: have a look at your `.Rprofile` file, and at the definitions of your `.First` and `.Last` functions. Also, the reason your message looks weird is probably because it tries to output greek in a weird encoding and this fails in the graphical windows. Try running R from the terminal if you can, and see if this error occurs there as well. if not, it may be an RStudio thing specifically

Comment: are you on a local or a network drive? In my experience, working on a local drive creates less problems. This is particularly true for Markdown documents which can cause problems while knitting on network drives.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answers. The problem was that I had open an R script file which I had deleted before. When I remove this script, Rstudio works fine.